# Unable to move button to right and expand input to fill space

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```html
<form role="search" method="get" id="bbp-search-form" action="https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/support-forums/search/">
  <div>
    <label class="screen-reader-text hidden" for="bbp_search">Search for:</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="bbp-search-request">
    <input tabindex="101" type="text" value="" name="bbp_search" id="bbp_search">
    <input tabindex="102" class="button" type="submit" id="bbp_search_submit" value="Search">
  </div>

  <div class="gdpos-power-link">
    <a href="https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/support-forums/search/">Advanced Search</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

What I wanted to try and do is move the `button` to the right and expand the `input` to fill the space.

- I tried using `float:right;` with the button and it does indeed move to the right.
- I then tried applying a `width: 100%;` to the `input` but it expands to the very right edge and pushing the button down underneath it.

Is it not possible to do what I what? I am not able to change the HTML at this stage and hope to do what I want via CSS adjustments.

## Update

When I try this addition CSS:

```
#bbp-search-form > div {
  display: flex;
}

#bbp-search-form > div input {
  flex: 1;
}
```

I end up with:

[image]

## Update

I tried:

```
#bbp-search-form > div:first-child {
  display: flex;
}

#bbp-search-form > div:first-child input {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How much? You can just set the width of the input to a pixel value like `width: 300px`. Or do you want it all the way to the edge but without the button moving down?

Comment: use flex for the parent and use flex-grow:1 for your input. ... float won't be of any help here.

Comment: @abney317 The latter. I was thinking of all the way to the edge but without moving the button down.

Comment: You're applying it to all the div's and input's, you need to target the right elements.

Comment: @VXp Thanks. Please see updated question.

Comment: #bbp_search {flex: 1} Since you have an id on that input, which is a good practice, make good use of it, so ignore/remove #bbp-search-form > div:first-child input and just use #bbp_search. That should do it. #bbp-search-form > div:first-child {display: flex;} is kinda fine, but would've been better with an id.

Comment: @VXp I still struggled with it. Sorry.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vares639/ Simple as that, if you're not getting this live, then we don't know all the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use flex box with flex-grow

```css
.my-row {
  display: flex;
}

.my-row input {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
<div class="my-row">
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

With your code

```css
#bbp-search-form > div:first-child {
  display: flex;
}

input[name="bbp_search"] {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<form role="search" method="get" id="bbp-search-form" action="https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/support-forums/search/">
  <div>
    <label class="screen-reader-text hidden" for="bbp_search">Search for:</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="bbp-search-request">
    <input tabindex="101" type="text" value="" name="bbp_search" id="bbp_search">
    <input tabindex="102" class="button" type="submit" id="bbp_search_submit" value="Search">
  </div>

  <div class="gdpos-power-link">
    <a href="https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/support-forums/search/">Advanced Search</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

## Update

I found this to be the simplest CSS to use:

```
#bbp-search-form > div:first-of-type { display: flex; }
#bbp-search-form #bbp_search { flex: 1; margin-right: 5px; }
#bbp-search-form #bbp_search_submit { margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; }
```

Comment: Thanks/ That does indeed look great. Sadly, the bbPress code does not seem to expose a class for us to style that parent `<div>`.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle `#bbp-search-form > div:first-child` to target the container div

Comment: Thanks. I am getting different results to you. Please see updated question. Please note that I have not "published" my custom CSS to the site yet.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Notice the `:first-child` in my comment

Comment: If I attach `:first-child` then it goes back to my original form display.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle You're applying it to all inputs, you need to target just the text input. Try using
```#bbp-search-form > div:first-child input[type=text] {  flex: 1;
}```